# Webflux drops when overflow strategy is buffer

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, backpressure

When I call `subscribe()` calls outside the reactive chain. Does it not follow the spring webflux's overflow strategy?

```kotlin
fooRepository.findOne()
    .doOnNext { barRepository.save(bar).subscribe() }
    .flatMap { ... }
```

I have this strange behavior which `barRepository.save` sometimes works and sometimes not with no error. I think it is being dropped.

When server is busy, can subscribe() calls inside doOnNext be dropped?

[This post](https://www.e4developer.com/2018/04/28/springs-webflux-reactor-parallelism-and-backpressure/) says default overflow strategy is BUFFER.

Does subscribe() calls inside doOnNext has different strategy?

Comment: You should not be subscribing, the subscriber is the calling client or whomever that is the final consumer. your application is the producer.

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that your subscription ends before persistence is completed.

`doOnNext()` is designed to perform some side-effect behavior and you should not implement business logic within those. So I believe that an exception thrown by your repository call or whatever happens there is not translated into your main reactive chain so you just simply lose control on what is inside.

If you need to make sure a business logic operation is done and not lost you'd better include in into the main flow through `flatMap()` operator.

Anyway, you can also add `.doOnError()` to `barRepository.save(bar).subscribe()` and log the issue.